# Using "quick" instead of "quickly" in this case

Tags: usage

When I express a desire for a certain happening to transpire as soon as possible can I say

> May that moment come quick!

or should I still stick to

> May that moment come quickly!

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either sentence. 'Quick' is one of those adverbs that can be used with or without the 'ly' at the end. [(Flat Adverbs)](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/flat-adverbs-are-flat-out-useful/)

Answer (score -1):

If you are in the USA you can use quick. For the rest of the world, use quickly, or you will be perceived as having inferior intellect.

Comment: I think this is too strong. "quick" can be used as an adverb in British English.